# How to get distinct array elements with postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, unique, postgresql-9.4

I have an array with duplicate values in postgres. For example:

```
SELECT cardinality(string_to_array('1,2,3,4,4', ',')::int[]) as foo
=> "foo"=>"5"
```

I would like to get unique elements, for example:

```
SELECT cardinality(uniq(string_to_array('1,2,3,4,4', ',')::int[])) as foo
=> -- No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Can I get unique elements of an array in postgres without using UNNEST ?

Comment: whats wrong with UNNEST? using UNNEST you will be able to SELECT DISTINCT and be done with the job..

Comment: There is a specific `uniq(int[])` function in the [`intarray` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html), but other than that, you have to use `unnest()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For integer arrays use [intarray extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html):

```
create extension if not exists intarray;
select cardinality(uniq(string_to_array('1,2,3,4,4', ',')::int[])) as foo
```

or the function

```
create or replace function public.array_unique(arr anyarray)
    returns anyarray
    language sql
as $function$
    select array_agg(distinct elem)
    from unnest(arr) as arr(elem) 
$function$;
```

for any array. You can easily modify the function to preserve the original order of the array elements:

```
create or replace function public.array_unique_ordered(arr anyarray)
    returns anyarray
    language sql
as $function$
    select array_agg(elem order by ord)
    from (
        select distinct on(elem) elem, ord
        from unnest(arr) with ordinality as arr(elem, ord)
        order by elem, ord
        ) s
$function$;
```

Example:

```
with my_data(arr) as (values ('{d,d,a,c,b,b,a,c}'::text[]))
select array_unique(arr), array_unique_ordered(arr)
from my_data

 array_unique | array_unique_ordered
--------------+----------------------
 {a,b,c,d}    | {d,a,c,b}
(1 row)
```

Comment: I ended up doing the function as you suggest. I find it a bit disappointing that this is not by default it postgres.

Comment: How to preserve orginal order of elements in the array?

Answer (score 15):

I prefer this syntax (about 5% faster)

```
create or replace function public.array_unique(arr anyarray)
returns anyarray as $body$
    select array( select distinct unnest($1) )
$body$ language 'sql';
```

using:

```
select array_unique(ARRAY['1','2','3','4','4']);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Should be built-in into Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Going off of @klin's accepted answer, I modified it to remove nulls in the process of choosing only the distinct values.

```
create or replace function public.array_unique_no_nulls(arr anyarray)
returns anyarray
language sql
as $function$
select array_agg(distinct a)
from (
    select unnest(arr) a 
) alias
where a is not null
$function$;
```