# update table cells to only have unique values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database table with a grade_range column, the rows of this column contain duplicate values all separated by a comma (like a list).

```
grade_range
"Pre-K, Pre-K, Pre-K"
"Pre-K, K-9, K-9"
"Pre-K, K-7, 9-12"
"Pre-K, K-7, K-7"
"Pre-K, K-6"
"Pre-K, K-5"
```

I want to update these records so that I am only left with the unique values in the rows of this column, like this

```
grade_range
"Pre-K"
"Pre-K, K-9"
"Pre-K, K-7, 9-12"
"Pre-K, K-7"
"Pre-K, K-6"
"Pre-K, K-5"
```

Distinct column values can be easily selected in SQL using -

```
SELECT DISTINCT grade_range FROM dev.school
```

but, I am not sure how to select/update distinct values inside a row-cell. One way I thought of doing was to manipulate this data in Excel and then updating records using an `UPDATE` statement based on the same `sid`s

Any suggestion on accomplishing this in SQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL brother

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to convert the comma seperated values to rows
then use distince then concatenate them again

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
    (
        @List varchar(max),
        @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
    )  
    RETURNS @RtnValue table 
    (

        ID int identity(1,1),
        Val varchar(max)
    ) 
    AS  
    BEGIN 
        While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
        Begin

            Insert Into @RtnValue (Val)
            Select 
                Val = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))

            Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
        End

        Insert Into @RtnValue (Val)
        Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

        Return
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st. Create a function to distinct an array**

Open `psql`. Inside psql type `\ef`. Replace the content with this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.array_unique(arr anyarray)
RETURNS anyarray 
LANGUAGE sql AS 
$function$
  select array( select distinct unnest($1) )
$function$
```

**2nd. Play the game**

Assuming each element constantly divided by comma and space. We can split per rows into array format, distinct it with previous function, then convert it back to a string.

```
SELECT 
   array_to_string(array_unique(regexp_split_to_array(grade, E', ')), ',') as grade_distinct, 
   grade 
FROM 
   your_table;
```

**Result**

```
localhost:5432 user@database=# 
SELECT 
   array_to_string(array_unique(regexp_split_to_array(grade, E', ')), ',') as grade_distinct, 
   grade 
FROM 
   tmp_stack_overflow;

 grade_distinct |        grade        
----------------+---------------------
 Pre-K          | Pre-K, Pre-K, Pre-K
 Pre-K,K-9      | Pre-K, K-9, K-9
 Pre-K,K-7,9-12 | Pre-K, K-7, 9-12
 Pre-K,K-7      | Pre-K, K-7, K-7
 K-6,Pre-K      | Pre-K, K-6
 K-5,Pre-K      | Pre-K, K-5
(6 rows)
```

Comment: array_unique function credit to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41725011/341959